# How can I lock contacts that are currently being edited?

Tags: contacts, contact-view

We often have a group of volunteers calling through the same list of people, eg we might have 20 people calling through lapsed members. Using Call Next is working well to make it easy on the volunteers, but we need to find a way to hide contacts that are currently being edited by another caller, so that they don't get double called. Randomising the order of the list so that volunteers were each presented with a different name would also work. Once the phone call has taken place and the status is saved they disappear from the call next dashlet so there is no issue there.

Comment: I think some folk would do this by assigning people to be called to specific volunteers

Comment: Thanks Pete, is there a way to do that automatically do you know? Perhaps by creating a new CiviRule?

Comment: Logic would be. Find Contacts for VolA to Call, create (or assign an existing) Activity to Vol A for all those contacts, repeat for VolB.